# Location updates are not working in Device Admin / Managed Work Profile Mode

Tags: android, geolocation, location, android-gps, device-admin

When location updates are requested with LocationManager as well as FusedLocationProviderClient, I'm unable to receive location updates in my app. So I have tried below code to allow the location updates in my app, but it is not working.

```
manager = (DevicePolicyManager)
            getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
if (manager.isProfileOwnerApp(getApplicationContext().getPackageName())) {
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, CommCareDeviceAdminReceiver.class);
        manager.setSecureSetting(componentName, Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE, String.valueOf(Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_HIGH_ACCURACY));
    }
```

I received following error in my logcat -

```
06-15 20:00:33.885 18226-18226/? W/System.err: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denial: Profile owners cannot update location_mode
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1684)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1637)
    at android.app.admin.IDevicePolicyManager$Stub$Proxy.setSecureSetting(IDevicePolicyManager.java:6238)
    at android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager.setSecureSetting(DevicePolicyManager.java:5533)
    at org.commcare.devicepolicycontroller.CommCareDeviceAdminReceiver.enableProfile(CommCareDeviceAdminReceiver.java:69)
    at org.commcare.devicepolicycontroller.CommCareDeviceAdminReceiver.onProfileProvisioningComplete(CommCareDeviceAdminReceiver.java:51)
    at android.app.admin.DeviceAdminReceiver.onReceive(DeviceAdminReceiver.java:665)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3061)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18(ActivityThread.java)
06-15 20:00:33.886 18226-18226/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1574)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
```

So far, I have found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950623/android-change-gps-status-when-app-is-device-administrator-enabled), which is not much helpful to me for now.
Can anyone please help me guide in this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After almost 5 days of research, I have found the solution to this issue.

> **This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45548476/work-around-for-device-admin-api-does-not-own-profile) helped me a lot to find a solution to this problem.**

To request enabling the Work/Managed Profile for Admin access, we need to do it as below:

```
/**
 * Initiates the managed profile provisioning. If we already have a managed profile set up on
 * this device, we will get an error dialog in the following provisioning phase.
 */
private void provisionManagedProfile() {
    Activity activity = getActivity();
    if (null == activity) {
        return;
    }

    PackageManager packageManager = activity.getPackageManager();

    if (!packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_MANAGED_USERS)) {
        String message = getString(R.string.managed_users_unsupported);
        HyperLog.e(Constants.TAG, message);
        ((TextView)activity.findViewById(R.id.setup_text)).setText(message);
        return;
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_PROVISION_MANAGED_PROFILE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
        intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_COMPONENT_NAME,
                CommCareDeviceAdminReceiver.getComponentName(activity));
    }
    else {
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_NAME,
                activity.getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
        intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, CommCareDeviceAdminReceiver.getComponentName(activity));
    }
    if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PROVISION_MANAGED_PROFILE);
        activity.finish();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Device provisioning is not enabled. Stopping.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

And once it is enabled, you need to add below code in [onEnabled](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DeviceAdminReceiver.html#onEnabled(android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent)) method of [DeviceAdminReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DeviceAdminReceiver). We will use [setPermissionGrantState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#setPermissionGrantState(android.content.ComponentName,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int)) method from [DevicePolicyManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager). Additionally, we can also prevent these managed profile user from going into safe mode by using [addUseRestriction](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#addUserRestriction(android.content.ComponentName,%20java.lang.String)) Method.

```
/**
* Handles events related to managed profile.
*/
public class MyDeviceAdminReceiver extends DeviceAdminReceiver {

    /**
    * Called after the administrator is first enabled
    */
    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onEnabled(context, intent);
        DevicePolicyManager manager =
            (DevicePolicyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
        if (manager != null) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

                //ADDING DYNAMIC LOCATIONS PERMISSIONS IS VERY IMPORTANT IS MANAGED PROFILE

                manager.setPermissionGrantState(getComponentName(context)
                        , "com.example.mypackagename"
                        , Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                        , DevicePolicyManager.PERMISSION_GRANT_STATE_GRANTED);
                manager.setPermissionGrantState(getComponentName(context)
                        , "com.example.mypackagename"
                        , Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                        , DevicePolicyManager.PERMISSION_GRANT_STATE_GRANTED);
                //------------------------------------------


                // To disable safe boot
                manager.addUserRestriction(getComponentName(context), UserManager.DISALLOW_SAFE_BOOT);
                // To enable safe boot again
                // manager.clearUserRestriction(admin, UserManager.DISALLOW_SAFE_BOOT);

                Log.i(TAG, "addUserRestriction is done");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code is working fine and properly tested.

I hope this might help someone looking for similar answers.

Thank You.